# Train model using Named entity

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, sentiment-analysis, named-entity-recognition, pos-tagger

I am looking on standford corenlp using the Named Entity REcognizer.I have different kinds of input text and i need to tag it into my own Entity.So i  started training my own model and it doesnt seems to be working.

For eg: my input text string is "Book of 49 Magazine Articles on Toyota Land Cruiser 1956-1987 Gold Portfolio http://t.co/EqxmY1VmLg http://t.co/F0Vefuoj9Q"

I go through the examples to train my own models and and look for only some words that I am interested in.

My jane-austen-emma-ch1.tsv looks like this

```
Toyota  PERS
Land Cruiser    PERS
```

From the above input text i am only interested in those two words. The one is 
Toyota and the other word is Land Cruiser.

The austin.prop look like this

```
trainFile = jane-austen-emma-ch1.tsv
serializeTo = ner-model.ser.gz
map = word=0,answer=1
useClassFeature=true
useWord=true
useNGrams=true
noMidNGrams=true
useDisjunctive=true
maxNGramLeng=6
usePrev=true
useNext=true
useSequences=true
usePrevSequences=true
maxLeft=1
useTypeSeqs=true
useTypeSeqs2=true
useTypeySequences=true
wordShape=chris2useLC
```

Run the following command to generate the ner-model.ser.gz file

java -cp stanford-corenlp-3.4.1.jar edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier -prop austen.prop

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String serializedClassifier = "edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.muc.7class.distsim.crf.ser.gz";
        String serializedClassifier2 = "C:/standford-ner/ner-model.ser.gz";
        try {
            NERClassifierCombiner classifier = new NERClassifierCombiner(false, false, 
                    serializedClassifier2,serializedClassifier);
            String ss = "Book of 49 Magazine Articles on Toyota Land Cruiser 1956-1987 Gold Portfolio http://t.co/EqxmY1VmLg http://t.co/F0Vefuoj9Q";
            System.out.println("---");
            List<List<CoreLabel>> out = classifier.classify(ss);
            for (List<CoreLabel> sentence : out) {
              for (CoreLabel word : sentence) {
                System.out.print(word.word() + '/' + word.get(AnswerAnnotation.class) + ' ');
              }
              System.out.println();
            }

        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Here is the output I am getting

```
Book/PERS of/PERS 49/O Magazine/PERS Articles/PERS on/O Toyota/PERS Land/PERS Cruiser/PERS 1956-1987/PERS Gold/O Portfolio/PERS http://t.co/EqxmY1VmLg/PERS http://t.co/F0Vefuoj9Q/PERS
```

which i think its wrong.I am looking for Toyota/PERS and Land Cruiser/PERS(Which is a multi valued fied.

Thanks for the Help.Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Why are you combining it with stanford-english-7class classifier. Whats the size of your training data (number of sentences/tokens)?

Comment: Thanks vihari.My training data is very just two fields which i mention in the tsv file and I am just playing around and slowly it will add up. i include the standfors classifier class and if I dont find any matching from there also look my trained data if any matching found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NERClassifier* is word level, that is, it labels words, not phrases. Given that, the classifier seems to be performing fine. If you want, you can hyphenate words that form phrases. So in your labeled examples and in your test examples, you would make "Land Cruiser" to "Land_Cruiser".

Comment: Thanks Sonal. If you look at my tsv file i only have two words one is Toyota and the other one Land cruiser and when i run the programme only these two words should mark as PERS and i beleive rest of the words should give as O but my outputs is different. I am not sure why the other words are comming as PERS for  eg Book/PERS of/PERS and the hperlink. Any thoughts. thanks for the help

Comment: How do we make the NERClassifier train and work for Pharses? Did the answer given below using RegEx work for you?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you should also put examples of `0` entities in your `trainFile`. As you gave it, the `trainFile` is just too simple for the learning to be done, it needs **both `0` and `PERSON` examples** so it doesn't annotate everything as `PERSON`. You're *not teaching it* about your not-of-interest entities. Say, like this:

```
Toyota  PERS
of    0
Portfolio    0
49    0
```

and so on.

Also, for **phrase-level** recognition you should look into `regexner`, where you can have **patterns** (patterns are good for us). I'm working on this with the `API` and I have the following code:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, regexner");
props.put("regexner.mapping", customLocationFilename);
```

with the following `customLocationFileName`:

```
Make Believe Town   figure of speech    ORGANIZATION
( /Hello/ [{ ner:PERSON }]+ )   salut   PERSON
Bachelor of (Arts|Laws|Science|Engineering) DEGREE
( /University/ /of/ [{ ner:LOCATION }] )    SCHOOL
```

and text: `Hello Mary Keller was born on 4th of July and took a Bachelor of Science. Partial invoice (€100,000, so roughly 40%) for the consignment C27655 we shipped on 15th August to University of London from the Make Believe Town depot. INV2345 is for the balance.. Customer contact (Sigourney Weaver) says they will pay this on the usual credit terms (30 days).`

The output I get

```
Hello Mary Keller is a salut
4th of July is a DATE
Bachelor of Science is a DEGREE
$ 100,000 is a MONEY
40 % is a PERCENT
15th August is a DATE
University of London is a ORGANIZATION
Make Believe Town is a figure of speech
Sigourney Weaver is a PERSON
30 days is a DURATION
```

For more info on how to do this you can look at the [example](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2265404) that got me going.

Comment: I used the following customLocationFilename:(/Make//Believe//Town) LOCATION
(/Hello/[{ner:PERSON}]+) SALUT
Bachelor of (Arts|Laws|Science|Engineering) DEGREE
(/University//of/[{ner:LOCATION}]) SCHOOL and I got result: '{Mary Keller}' is a {PERSON}
'{4th of July}' is a {DATE}
'{Bachelor of Science}' is a {DEGREE}
'{$ 100,000}' is a {MONEY}
'{40 %}' is a {PERCENT}
'{15th August}' is a {DATE}
'{University of London}' is a {ORGANIZATION}
'{Make Believe Town}' is a {ORGANIZATION}
...Error in Make Believe Town, Hello Mary Keller, Univ. of London... kindly suggest.

Comment: One thing you need to do is add a third column in the customLocationFilename, which represents the annotations that your custom trained NERClassifier can *override*, like this: (/Make//Believe//Town) LOCATION ORGANIZATION

Comment: Thank you for the response. Change Done.. Still not working. Still getting (1)Make Believe Town as ORGANIZATION (2)University of London as ORGANIZATION  (3) Mary Keller as PERSON. Bachelor of Science DEGREE is coming correct. I am not clear why.     Do I need to put a space or a TAB between LOCATION and ORGANIZATION.

Comment: Yes! all columns are divided by tabs. My bad for not emphasizing that.