# How to train Stanford CRF NER from a tsv file

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, stanford-nlp, sentiment-analysis, named-entity-recognition

I am looking to train my own model, e.g. this string I need to run through my trained model: "Book of 49 Magazine Articles on Toyota Land Cruiser 1956-1987 Gold Portfolio http://t.co/EqxmY1VmLg http://t.co/F0Vefuoj9Q"

The tsv file looks like this:

```
Toyota  PERS
Land    PERS
```

When I run it through the programme:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String serializedClassifier2 = "C:/standford-ner/ner-model.ser.gz";
      try {
            NERClassifierCombiner classifier = new NERClassifierCombiner(false, false, 
                     serializedClassifier2);
            String ss = "Book of 49 Magazine Articles on Toyota Land Cruiser 1956-1987 Gold Portfolio http://t.co/EqxmY1VmLg http://t.co/F0Vefuoj9Q";
            System.out.println("---");
            List<List<CoreLabel>> out = classifier.classify(ss);
            for (List<CoreLabel> sentence : out) {
              for (CoreLabel word : sentence) {
                System.out.print(word.word() + '/' + word.get(AnswerAnnotation.class) + ' ');
              }
              System.out.println();
            }


        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Here is the output I am getting:

```
Book/PERS of/PERS 49/O Magazine/PERS Articles/PERS on/O Toyota/PERS Land/PERS Cruiser/O 1956-1987/PERS Gold/PERS Portfolio/PERS http://t.co/EqxmY1VmLg/PERS http://t.co/F0Vefuoj9Q/PERS
```

For me, the output is wrong. I need to get `Book/O of/O`.  I am not sure how it's getting this value, e.g. "book" is not mentioned in my tsv file. The words I have not mentioned in the tsv file should come as `O`. This tsv file is just the beginning; I have many more words to add.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Train model using Named entity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29755910/train-model-using-named-entity)

Answer (score 1):

You've given the classifier training data where 100% of the data is one class: `PERS`. Since 100% of your training data is that class, it's going to give you back 100% of assignments to that class.

For the algorithm, `O` is simply another class. You've given it no examples of `O`, so it will classify nothing as `O`.

The [Stanford NER CRF FAQ](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/crf-faq.shtml) gives [an example of training data](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/ner-example/jane-austen-emma-ch1.tsv):

```
CHAPTER O
I   O
Emma    PERS
Woodhouse   PERS
,   O
handsome    O
,   O
clever  O
,   O
and O
rich    O
,   O
with    O
a   O
comfortable O
home    O
...
```

So you can see, there, they tag every token *in situ*, with plenty of examples of the `O` class. I'm not entirely familiar with the workings of the CRF classifier, but I suspect you need to give it actual data, tagged appropriately, not just a list of examples of members of your target classes.

That begs another question, though--if you simply want to match strings for this task, why are you using NER? Why not just match strings? If that's your goal, it will save you serious headache to skip the sophisticated NLP. You'll get results faster that are easier to tweak by hand.

Comment: Thanks Dan.My problem is I am getting millions of input txt, I need to tag it as my own entity.If I use the NLP "english.muc.7class.distsim.crf.ser.gz", I  cannot match all the entity I am looking for.So I am not sure I can match 100% of the input data to my own tsv file bcz I am not sure how the input text looks like to match my own tsv file.Is there any better way of doing this using NLP  where I am not familiar.Thanks for the help.

Comment: There's not really any NLP magic you're missing. NLP isn't so much magic as it is generalizing from human blood and sweat from the annotation process. What you get is only as good as your training data. If your training data deviates significantly from the task you're trying to do, you can either make new training data or find a new way to do the task. You could also try appending your training data to another larger, readily available set of training data, though that could help or hurt depending on the nature of your task.

Comment: Thanks Dan. Can u please point me some well set training data. I will add something to there where i am looking for. thanks

Comment: The Jane Austen data is a good example, but your task seems particular enough that you'd want to follow in the form of what they did there, but with your own goals in mind. Jane Austen probably didn't have any examples of Toyota Land Cruisers, and a lot of data sets that are available already--even more modern ones--probably don't either. If you really want, you could come up with your own classes--Make, Model, etc. I'm not totally familiar with CRF classifiers, but I suspect they should be able to infer some details of the target set you're looking at.