# how to Create Name Entity Recognition and evaluate its performance in terms of precision and recall?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, weka, stanford-nlp, opennlp

I am working on aspects identification (explicit and implicit aspects) from a movie review dataset. Here, aspects could be actors, directors, production companies, music, plot, movie type etc. Despite searching a lot, I have come to know I need a NER (name entity recognition) for movie review dataset. Unfortunately, there is no NER available for my dataset.

My Questions are:

1. how can I evaluate my "Movie NER" in terms of *precision*, *recall* and F1 *measure*?
2. what tool should I use for this purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Answers:**

1. If you don't have gold data, first you will need to annotate and create your own gold data set. Then you can use this data for precision, recall, F1 measure calculations.
2. For NER purpose you can use Machine Learning based approach. I can suggest you to use [CRF++](https://taku910.github.io/crfpp/). You will need to define your own Tag Set and annotate data using IOB technique and use CRF++ for model training and testing purpose. You can use [conlleval.pl](http://www.cnts.ua.ac.be/conll2000/chunking/output.html) to calculate accuracy of the algorithm in terms of precision and recall.

Comment: so far what I understood is that I have to tag my dataset by actor, producer etc. For instance "I like <actor>johnny depp</actor> because he is a <opinion>good actor</opinion>" and use CRF++ for evaluation?

Comment: CRF++ will be used for ML purpose and conlleval.pl will be used for accuracy calculations. For CRF++, you will need to follow "IOB Tagging" Scheme.

Comment: hello, i am working with crf++, however, I am dealing with a lots of problems because there is not much help available. I have a training file but when I try to train with template file I am having this error: encoder.cpp(57): feature_index.cpp(109): inconsistent column size: 3 4 final.txt
One thing I want to tell you I am using template file available on site, I didn't make it for my training file. The reason behind this is I dont really understands template programing. Please help me regarding this.

Comment: """inconsistent column size: 3 4 final.txt""" - In your training file you are having inconsistent number of columns. You can write simple split line code and find exact line where there are 4 columns.

Comment: alright, this is an exert of my traing file:

it PRP S
's POS S
got VBD S
a DT S
head NN S
start NN S
in IN S
this DT S
movie NN S
starring VBG S
jamie NN B_NAME
lee NN M_NAME
curtis NN E_NAME
and CC S
another DT S
baldwin NN B_NAME
brother NN E_NAME
-LRB- -LRB- S
william NN S
this DT S
time NN S
-RRB- -RRB- S
in IN S
a DT S
story NN S

Comment: You can write simple split line code and find exact line where there are 4 columns.

Comment: can you tell me what format stanfordcore nlp crfclassifier accept? I meam to say stanford crf accept IOB tagging schemes? I want to use standford its will be more flexible in generating feature templates

Comment: Yes it uses similar format. check : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29755910/train-model-using-named-entity , http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/crf-faq.shtml#a , https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lucaventurini/PImpStanfordNer4Nerd/master/HelloWorld/jane-austen-emma-ch1.tsv

Comment: RAVI, is that possible that I can define my own features in NERFeatureFactory? if it is possible how can I define them? I want to create a model I will predict Actor_name, Movie_name, Driector_name, Production_Company by learning my feature sets. I have lot of questions regarding NER classifiers. can you give me your email id so I can discuss my problem with you?